# Is Judge Dredd a psychic himself?

Tags: analysis, dredd

In the very beginning of *Dredd (2012)*, when the officer asks Anderson about the person who's with her, she begins to describe Dredd and her head tilts and she says "I even detect". The officer cuts her off and says "That's enough.."

Now, when Dredd is shot by the armor piercing rounds of another judge and drops to his knees he asks the other to wait.. And as he does and enters his monologue, Anderson shoots and Dredd responds, "Wait for her to shoot you".

So does this mean that Dredd is a psychic?

Comment: No. I am not psychic. I saw Rookie Anderson creep up behind the bad judge and timed myself.

Comment: @Dredd , Hilarious man. Thanking to rename myself to Batman! LOL! :-D

Comment: Thank you guys.. My interpretation was that when the lady officer introduced Anderson she said "she's the best we've come across in years" I just read into that too much and figured that was also part of the reason why she chose Dredd to Evaluate her aside from him being the best judge in Mega City and that he was not as a powerful Psychic as her being that his belief in the law and upholding it to the fullest is so strong so he doesn't use it to get into people's minds cause he wants to go by the letter of the law instead of his own personal feelings or perceptions or circumstances..

Answer (score 9):

Dredd in the movie was by no means a psychic. The scene that you're talking about, Judge Dredd after he was hit by that armor piercing round and was sitting on the floor he might have seen Anderson coming behind the bad guy after he had moved right next to confront Dredd which would have made him say wait to buy him some time.

Answer (score 8):

The interview scene you describe was discussed [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/9331/5589) and is, in my opinion, nicely explained.

No, I don't think Dredd is a psychic. There too many tell-signs.

For example, the scene before MaMa clan starts shooting those three big guns. He had to go there and take a peek. A psychic would read it from the nearby corner. As we see, he goes by his guts and brute force. That's the only way for him.

Also, he wouldn't have to ask why Anderson didn't bring her helmet; he'd know it already, if he was also a psychic.

The Dredd is The Law. That's his alpha and omega. And, since the movie is following the comic very closely (and was much praised for that by the fans), I'd say there is no chance they wanted to include anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Dredd is a clone. He was cloned from the DNA of the first Chief Judge in 2066.

That's what she was sensing in all likelyhood. But Dredd doesn't know that yet at this point in the movie - it was a nod to the in-crowd.